# RxSwift: onDisposed activated before Alamofire return data

Tags: swift, alamofire, rx-swift

I'm trying to get the JSON data from REST (swift 2.3) with rxSwift and Alamofire. This is my code:

```
  func getArticles(articlesReq: ArticlesReq) - > Observable < [Article] > {
      return Observable < [Article] > .create {
          observer in
              let request = Alamofire.request(.POST, apiPath, parameters: DataHelper().convertStringToDictionary(JSONString), encoding: .JSON)
                  .responseArray {
                      (response: Response < [Article], NSError > ) in
                          if let articlesArray = response.result.value {
                              observer.on(.Next(articlesArray))
                          }
                          observer.on(.Completed)
                  }
          return AnonymousDisposable {
              request.cancel()
          }

      }

  }

  getArticles(articlesReq).observeOn(MainScheduler.instance)
      .subscribe(
          onNext: {
              data in
              print(data)
          },
          onError: {
              error in
              print(error)
          },
          onCompleted: {
              print("Completed")
          },
          onDisposed: {
              print("Disposed")
          }
      ).addDisposableTo(db)
```

onDisposed return data before Alamofire.request return data (onNext, onError, onCompleted not return data ). How to wait for a response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to keep a strong reference to `disposbag` like this:

```
let disposeBag = DisposeBag()

func setupRx() {

  getArticles(articlesReq).observeOn(MainScheduler.instance)
      .subscribe(onNext: {
          print("onNext")
        // ... use $0 parameter
      }, onError: {
          print("onError")
        // ... use $0 parameter
      }, onCompleted: { 
          print("onCompelete")
      }, onDisposed: nil)
  .addDisposableTo(disposeBag)

}
```

Your `disposeBag` should live longer than response.

Hope this may help.